# How to unmask/disable or clear a textbox in JavascriptJquery using MVC razor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a text box

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" name="searchField"/>
```

and three radio buttons. I need to mask text box on select of specific radio button selection. I have successfully done with it. But on third radio button I want text box to just clear without any masking, just an open field. So, if we select Radio button 1, Text Box will masked accordingly but then we select Radio button 3. Masking remain in place. I want to remove it then.

Forgive the bad English. Thanks is advance.

Code used for masking.

```
$("#mytextbox").mask("999-9999-9999");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the sample code below..

```
$(document).on('click', "input:radio[name=xxxx]", function () {

          var val = $("input:radio[name=xxxx]:checked").val();       
              var mask = "999-9999-9999";
            if(val == "the value of 3rd radiobutton")
               {

                 $("#mytextbox").unmask(mask);
                 } 
             });
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Please tell me what to do for 2nd masking? As I said I have 3  radio buttons, 2 have different masking and 3rd one is blank text box? i passed 1st radio button mask's value in unmask parameter. What to do for 2nd one?

Comment: @AffanShahab assign to another variabel and unmask it eg: `var mask1 ="999/999"; inside if along with same code do $("#mytextbox").unmask(mask1);` check and tell..hope it works

Comment: I dont know why but I didn't have to to put new code..     var mask = "999-9999-9999";
        $("#mytextbox").unmask(mask); working fine for both conditions